# Angular4: Object created once, appears multiple times in the template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In my angular app, I POST some form data to the server, receive the response, and attach the received object as the last item in a list - this list is displayed in the template with an *ngFor.

Something odd is happening. The component registers addition of the object to the list only ONCE, however, for some reason, it appears multiple times in the template.

How many times? It depends. If the component's change detection strategy has run n times, the newly added object is shown n times.

Appreciate any tips with this bug!

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: Share your code.